# MATLAB error - ??? Attempt to reference field of non-structure array

Tags: matlab, sorting, insertion-sort

I'm writing an insertion sort in MATLAB. I called my function like this:

```
>> A = [5 4 3 2 1]

A =

     5     4     3     2     1

>> insertion_sort(A)
```

but when I run it I get the error

```
??? Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.

    Error in ==> insertion_sort at 6
        for j=2:original.length
```

Here's my original code:

```
function sorted = insertion_sort(original)

    for j=2:original.length
        key = original(j);
        i = j-1;
        while i > 0 && original(i) > key
            original(i+1) = original(i);
            i = i-1;
        end
        original(i+1) = key;
    end 

sorted = original;

end
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `numel(original)` instead of `original.length`.  MatLab matrices are primitive types, not objects, and they don't have a length property.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `numel(original)` instead of `original.length`. [Fundamental data types](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/fundamental-matlab-classes.html) don't have a `length` method, so MATLAB mistakenly thinks you are trying to access a field named `length` in a [structure](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html), which `original` is not.